# Как вывести данные с pyton в эксель

Tags: python

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/30/Show/England-Tottenham')  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
players_lines = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//tbody[@id='player-table-statistics-body']/tr")
results = {}
for player in players_lines:
    name = player.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span').text
    rating = player.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//td[contains(@class,'rating')]").text
    results[name] = rating
 
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Например с помощью `pandas`, устанавливаем зависимости `openpyxl` `pip install openpyxl`

```
import pandas as pd
...   
df = pd.DataFrame(list(results.items()), columns=['name', 'rating'])
df.to_excel('England-Tottenham.xlsx')
```